# How can editors change the width of table cells in the RTE of TYPO3 7.6?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, rte

How can editors resize table cells in the RTE manually? It's not possible to set the width of a cell by resizing the cell with the mouse or a numeric value in the cell properties. At least I haven't found a possibility to enable that.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/7.6/Configuration/PageTsconfig/interfaceConfiguration/Index.html#rteresize

Greets,
David

Comment: Thx, but my question was not regarding resizing the RTE window but the cell of a table that an editor can place into the RTE.

Comment: If you right-click in a cell you can adjust cell-properties.
As fixed width is usually deprecated you could define classes / styles that reflect available widths.